# Расстягивание изображения на всю ширину экрана

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, html5, изображения

Вот мой макет[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема с волнистым синим фоном внизу. Мне надо ее задавать как фоновую для того нижнего блока или как? Но у меня wrapper ограниченный, и больше него картинка не растягивается.

```css
.wrapper{ 
 height: 100%;
 width: 970px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding-left: 5px;
 padding-right: 5px;
}

#bg-image {
 background: url(../img/bg.png) repeat-x;
 background-size: 100%; 
 height: 420px;
}

#contacts {
 width: 100%;
 height: 420px;
 padding-top: 75px;
 margin-top: -40px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="wrapper">
          ...
        </div>
        <div id="bg-image"> 
   <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="contacts">
     ...
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
   <div id="footer">
    <div id="footer-block" class="right">
                  ...
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Я сделал вот так. Но это ужасные костыли. Как это правильно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте отрицательный margin. И ради всего святого не используйте id.
http://codepen.io/Zoxon/pen/avZjQy

```css
.page__wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #add8e6;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.page__header {
  background: #f00;
  height: 80px;
}
.page__main {
  background: #008000;
  height: 200px;
}
.page__footer {
  padding-top: 40px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  background: #90ee90;
  height: 80px;
}
.footer__inner {
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="page__wrapper">
    <div class="page__header">
      <header class="header">header</header>
    </div>
    <div class="page__main">
      <main class="content">content</main>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="page__footer">
    <footer class="footer">
      <div class="footer__inner">footer</div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. А не могли бы объяснить - почему id лучше не использовать?

Comment: @Влад id плох тем что у него высокая специфичность

Если к одному элементу одновременно применяются противоречивые стилевые правила, то более высокий приоритет имеет правило, у которого значение специфичности селектора больше.

Здесь хорошо объясняется http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/kaskadirovanie